# TeamCity and JIRA?

Tags: teamcity, jira, bamboo, youtrack

Is it possible for TeamCity to integrate to JIRA like how Bamboo integrates to JIRA? I couldnt find any documentation on JetBrains website that talks about issue-tracker integration.

FYI: I heard that TeamCity is coming out with their own tracker called Charisma. Is that true?

Comment: Wrt 2nd question: JetBrains (TeamCity) do have their own tracker, Charisma (Charizma?). If you try to file a bug report for TeamCity you will see it: http://jetbrains.net/tracker/welcome/TW . But I don't know if they are "coming out" with it.

Comment: I'm keen on this too, I'm going to write a plugin to show builds as a project tab http://www.atlassian.com/better-together/images/bamboo_jira_version.png

Comment: Scott: if you could do that, that'd be awesome!

Comment: I'm setting up our company jira so I'll be doing this next week, I can't use guest access so its pretty much what you get from rss and status widget pages http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Enabling+the+Status+Widget+for+Build+Configurations

Comment: Jetbrains' tracker is now called [You Track](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/)

Comment: By the way, if JIRA is configured to use Windows login, would Teamcity be able to connect to it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TeamCity 5 EAP has support for showing issues from Jira on the tabs of your build.

[EAP Release Notes](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TW/Darjeeling+5.0+EAP+Release+Notes)

you still don't have the integration in Jira itself which I would prefer

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is this plugin
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stiltsoft.jira.teamcity

Comment: It's worth noting that this plugin is (_still_) incompatible with Atlassian's hosted offering: JIRA Cloud (formerly known as JIRA OnDemand).

Answer (score 4):

TeamCity does not have extensive integration with JIRA as Bamboo does, and I am not aware of a plugin that provides it. TeamCity does however, offer a generic integration option to external sites which can be used for basic JIRA integration.

From their documentation:

> TeamCity allows to map patterns in VCS change comments to arbitrary HTML pieces using regular expression search and replace patterns. One of the most common usages is to map an issue ID mentioning into a hyperlink to the issue page in the issue tracking system.

Read more here: [Mapping External Links in Comments](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/Mapping+External+Links+in+Comments)

I haven't set this up yet on our local TeamCity, so I can't testify as to how well it works.

Comment: that Jira mapping worked for me without having to change the regex. Result.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, they are comming out with their own issue tracker. 
Read more in this blogpost:
[first eap for jetbrains issue tracker Charisma](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2009/05/21/first-eap-for-jetbrains-issue-tracker/)**

you can try it here [Charisma](http://jetbrains.net/tracker/issues/TW)
and here you can see [video for some of the features](http://jetbrains.net/tracker/welcome)

you can download the EAP version from here
[Charisma EAP download](http://jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TSYSPUB/Early+Access+Program)

Comment: I think Charisma was the internal name for what is now YouTrack

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity does have a free plugin for Atlassian Confluence.  Its provides a nice way to show your build status on your wiki.

You can find it in the Atlassian marketplace:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stiltsoft.confluence.extra.confluence-teamcity-plugin

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity has 3 build in Issue Tracking Systems:

1.BugZilla
2.JIRA
3.YouTrack

And there's a way to install the custom plugin for other ITS.
I did an integration with FogBugz issue tracking system with TeamCity 9.x.
https://github.com/jozefizso/teamcity-fogbugz